# draw only selected item from a scene in opengl

Tags: c++, glsl

I am using OpenGL Shading language along with SDL. I have a static scene with moving objects and the general structure of program is as follows:

```
initialize(){
//init meshes
}
display(){
//draw commands for static scene
//draw commands for moving objects
}
main()
{
   initialize()
     while(repeat)
     {
     display();
     //swap buffers or flush drawing commands
     }
 }
```

I need to draw static 'scene' but drawing it only once can be sufficient unlike moving objects. Is there a way to redraw only what needs to be redrawn?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23938239/3530129.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making 3D game, you can put entire static scene into single VBO and then draw it with single function call.

If you're making 2D game, you can draw it to texture and then draw a fullscreen quad with this texture.